# UIVisualEffect view Should not have value less than 1, this interferes with blurring in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, alpha, uivisualeffectview, xcode8

In one of my iOS app i am using iOS native component ***VisualEffectView with Blur*** to get blur effect.

For my User Interface requirement, i had set visual effect view's alpha value as 0.85, then Xcode throwing a compile time warning saying **UIVisualEffect view Should not have value less than 1, this interferes with blurring**. How do i bypass this warning without making my alpha value as 1.

I am using Xcode 8.3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivisualeffectview)  state :

> When using the  UIVisualEffectView  class, avoid alpha values that are
>   less than 1

Comment: Apple is saying, Setting the alpha to less than 1 on the visual effect view or any of its superviews causes many effects to look incorrect or not show up at all. Then why can't apple restrict to set alpha value less than 1.

Comment: @krishnarjun-banoth you can not set alpha value less than 1 on visual effect view but you can set alpha on its content view.

Comment: Thanks for your patience but i am not benefitted by setting alpha on content view.